# shell startup command

Tags: linux, shell

I want the following script command to be executed automatically when ever I log in to shell.

```
script /home/user/mylog_$(date '+%Y%m%d').log
```

I forget to run this command most of the times :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you start an interactive *login* bash shell, it will execute all commands put in `~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the particular shell that you are using.

For `bash`, add the line to `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Alan, ~/.bashrc is invoked for interactive *non-login* shells, he'll want ~/.bash_profile for this one